# Calculate seasonality and trend of time series data for each cluster

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, time-series, pivot-table

I have this time series data , now I want to calculate the  trend seasonality type (multiplicative or additive) for each cluster of APMC and commodities using '**modal_price**'. The dataset has around 60,000 such rows with APMC and Cluster being the same but the date as changing  . The dataset is as follows :

```
             APMC |   Commodity  | qtl _weight| min_price | max_price | modal_price | district_name | Year | Month
date
2014-12-01  Akole   bajri            40              1375        1750      1563          Ahmadnagar  2014   12
2014-12-01  Akole   paddy-unhusked   346             1400        1800      1625          Ahmadnagar  2014   12
2014-12-01  Akole   wheat            55              1500        1900       1675         Ahmadnagar  2014   12
2014-12-01  Akole   bhagar/vari      59              2000        2600       2400         Ahmadnagar  2014   12
2014-12-01  Akole   gram              9              3200        3300       3235         Ahmadnagar  2014   12
2014-12-01  Jamkhed cotton           44199           3950        4033       3991         Ahmadnagar  2014   12
2014-12-01  Jamkhed bajri            846             1300        1488       1394         Ahmadnagar  2014   12
2014-12-01  Jamkhed wheat(husked)    155             1879        2231       2055         Ahmadnagar  2014   12
2014-12-01  Kopar   gram             421             1983        2698       2463         Ahmadnagar  2014   12
2014-12-01  Kopar   greengram         18             6734        7259       6759         Ahmadnagar  2014   12
2014-12-01  Kopar   soybean          1507            2945        3247       3199         Ahmadnagar  2014   12
2016-11-01  Sanga   wheat(husked)    222             1730        2173       1994         Ahmadnagar  2016   11
```

Now I tried pivot table for this using (APMC,Commodity and date as index) but that doesn't help in calculating the mean(to calculate trend) for each cluster(APMC,Commodity). I just need to know how do i calculate  mean for each cluster(APMC,Commodity) using 'modal_price' and ADD that as a COLUMN in the dataframe/pivot-table .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a groupby will give you what you need for the trend and then transform will give you the ability to project it back onto the same index?
Something like:

```
# group by your cluster
g = df.groupby(["Year", "APMC", "Commodity"])
# determine the trend per cluster but finalise back into original diimensions
trend = g.modal_price.transform(lambda x: x.mean())
df["trend"] = trend
```

Comment: And what if I have to calculate the rolling mean for the same for each season?

Comment: Amended above to include "Year" in the groupby.

Comment: Shouldn't month be included ? As trend is on monthly base . Also what about rolling mean (). How do I go about that . Some commodities are for 3-4 months only , how do I set window_size for such cases

Comment: A trend is on whatever basis you want, however, your question asked for "mean(to calculate trend) for each cluster(APMC,Commodity) for each year". Amend your question or ask a new question if you want a rolling average.

Comment: On a side note, if you want to groupby date attributes (year, month, dow) you don't need to project out a column for it, you can do something like df.groupby(df.column.dt.year). Saves you a column or 3